# How to randomize multi-page form using SESSION variables?

Tags: php, arrays, random, pagination, session-variables

So essentially I have a session login/registration system in php and redirect the user to the start.php file that will show a navigation that is read from an array.

This is my scenario:

After user signs in successfully with `login.html` and `login.php`, redirect user to `start.php` or allow user to go to `start.php`. In `start.php`, randomly select one php from `sql1.php` - `sql10.php` (with random functions) and add it as a link in `start.php` (an example shown so that user can navigate to the selected page).

For example, if `sql3.php` is selected, then the user will be able to click and visit `sql3.php` from `start.php` after signing in.

When a user clicks on Next Page, a new page will be randomly selected from `sql1.php` - `sql10.php`, excluding those which have already been selected.  For example, if the user clicks on `sql3.php`, the page of `sql3.php` will display new information e.g. (`sql7.php` and have a new next page) with the new selected page (assume it is `sql7.php` this time and `sql3.php` shouldn’t be selected).

Allow user to click on either Prev page to return to previous page or next page every time when the user lands on a new page. If all the `sql1.php` - `sql10.php` files are randomly selected in the above process, then in the last 
selected page, don’t display the link to Next Page.

*code as followed*

```
session_start();

if( !isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {
    header("Location: login.html");
}
$stack = array(); 
array_push($stack, 'sql1.php');
array_push($stack, 'sql2.php');
array_push($stack, 'sql3.php');
array_push($stack, 'sql4.php');
array_push($stack, 'sql5.php');
array_push($stack, 'sql6.php');
array_push($stack, 'sql7.php');
array_push($stack, 'sql8.php');
array_push($stack, 'sql9.php');
array_push($stack, 'sql10.php');

$orderedstack = array();
$unorderedstack = array();

if(isset($_SESSION['stack'], $_SESSION['orderedstack'], $_SESSION['unorderedstack'])){
    $stack = $_SESSION['stack'];
    $orderedstack = $_SESSION['orderedstack'];
    $unorderedstack = $_SESSION['unorderedstack'];
}

$count = count($unorderedstack);

if(!empty($stack)){
    $i = 0;
    while($i < 10){
        $i ++;
        $mixing = $stack[array_rand($stack)];
        /* array_rand randomly returns the the key of $stack. In this scenario it's mixing the keys of the array */
        array_push($unorderedstack, $mixing);
        $coreinfo = array_search($mixing,$stack);
        if($coreinfo!==false){
            unset($stack[$coreinfo]);
        }
        /* Using array_search, once the file is located, the keys of the found file is used for the buttons ($currentpage, $lastpage and $thenextpage)*/
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['next'])){
    if(count($orderedstack) < 10){
        $thenextpage = array_pop($unorderedstack);
        array_push($orderedstack, $thenextpage);
        $coreinfo = array_search($thenextpage,$orderedstack);
        if($coreinfo!==false && count($orderedstack) > 1){
            $currentfile = $orderedstack[$coreinfo-1];
        }
        if($coreinfo!==false && count($orderedstack) > 2){
            $lastpage = $orderedstack[$coreinfo-2];
        }
    }
}    

if(isset($_GET['back'])){
    $prevfile = array_pop($orderedstack);
    array_push($orderedstack, $prevfile);    
    $coreinfo = array_search($prevfile,$orderedstack);
    if($coreinfo!==false  && count($orderedstack) > 2){
        $currentfile = $orderedstack[$coreinfo-2];
    }
    if($coreinfo!==false && count($orderedstack) > 3){
        $lastpage = $orderedstack[$coreinfo-3];
    }
    if($coreinfo!==false && count($orderedstack) > 2){
        $thenextpage = $orderedstack[$coreinfo-1];
    }
    $switch = array_pop($orderedstack);
    array_push($unorderedstack, $prevfile);
}

/*Using echo we created HTML tags and elements to create a form. We added buttons to navigate between the files. The form's method is get, since it's insensitive info, and the button's names is back and next. Using if statements and binary search, we were able to make sure no files were being repeated.*/

?>    
<html>
<head>
<title>Start.php  - Reece, Courtney and Ros</title>    
<style>
.box{
    text-align: center;     
}    
p{
    color: red;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
</style>    
</head>    
<body>    

<?php
if (count($orderedstack) <=1) {
    echo '<h1>start.php</h1>';
    echo '<div class="box">
    <form method="GET">';
        echo '<button name = "next">This button will select a random sql{i}.php file</button>
    </form>
    </div>';
} elseif (count($orderedstack) <=2) {
    echo '<h1><a href=" '. $currentfile . '">' . $currentfile . ' </a></h1>
    <br>';
    echo '<div class="box">
        <form method="GET">
            <button name="back">Go back to start.php starting page</button>';
            echo '<p>' . $currentfile . ' is being displayed</p>';
            echo '<button name = "next">The next sql{i}.php file will be ' . $thenextpage . '</button>
        </form>
    </div>';
} elseif (count($orderedstack) < 10) {
    echo '<h1><a href=" '. $currentfile . '">' . $currentfile . ' </a></h1>
    <br>';
    echo '<div class="box">
    <form method="GET">
        <button name="back">The previous sql{i}.php file was ' . $lastpage . '</button>';
        echo '<p>' . $currentfile . ' is being displayed</p>';
        echo '<button name = "next">The next sql{i}.php file will be ' . $thenextpage . '</button>
    </form>
    </div>';
} elseif (count($orderedstack) == 10) {
    echo '<h1><a href=" '. $currentfile . '">' . $currentfile . ' </a></h1>
    <br>';
    echo '<div class="box">
    <form method="GET">
        <button name="back">You reached the last file, press here to go back</button>';
        echo '<p>' . $currentfile . ' is being displayed</p>
    </form>
    </div>';
}

$_SESSION['stack'] = $stack;
$_SESSION['unorderedstack'] = $unorderedstack;
$_SESSION['orderedstack'] = $orderedstack;
?>

<button type="button"><a href="logout.php" >Logout</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Would love to know of a shortened way of doing it, but still using stack or is there any other ways that I can carry it out without stack?

I would like to get it optimized for web use if possible for future projects.

Comment: If that's your array, why not `$stack = ['sql1.php', 'sql2.php', ...];`, rather than all those pushes?

Comment: Would suggest reading up on [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php), specifically iterators.

Comment: @Michael have you left us?

Answer (score 0):

On **start.php** you need:

```
// build a list of sql.php pages
$_SESSION[ 'sql_pages' ] = explode( ' ', 'sql'.implode( '.php sql', range(1, 10) ).'.php' );

// randomize those pages
shuffle($_SESSION[ 'sql_pages' ]);

$pop = array_pop($_SESSION[ 'sql_pages' ]);
echo '<a href="'.$pop.'">'.$pop.'</a>';
```

---

and on the **sql{x}.php** pages you need:

```
if(isset($_SESSION[ 'sql_pages' ]) && count($_SESSION[ 'sql_pages' ]) > 0)
{
    $pop = array_pop($_SESSION[ 'sql_pages' ]);
    echo '<a href="'.$pop.'">'.$pop.'</a>';
}
else
{
    echo 'No more pages!';
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I would say _you need_ to use `implode()`, `range()`, and `explode()`.  Probably better to say _you could_.  I think some developers would find the code to be more readable if the array was declared in a function-less manner.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks, but if I am gonna "give someone a fish" then I am at least gonna make them work hard to pull the fish into their boat. Yes, my use of functions is overkill but OP is more than welcome to define that array any way that they wish, hence the helpful comments. Besides, this question reeks of homework so if my code is used verbatim then I hope the instructor is smart enough to gauge this student's ability and inquire about the complex use of functions.

Comment: I got the vibe like this was a dad doing something for his kids.  Don't know.

Answer (score 0):

To "optimize" I have tried to reduce total function calls throughout the course of the application by storing the vital components in the SESSION array.

You don't need to store the `sql#.php` string in your stack array -- only the integers, since that is the only variable part of the string.

As your project expands, there is a single point of adjustment for the stack array.  Additionally, you could even draw the `sql` filenames from the directory if you wanted to ditch the `range()` call.

By using an `include` to place the sql file's contents on the page, you never have to reconfigure the form destination.

I have tested this to work on my localhost...

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
/* if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {
    header("Location: login.html");
} */
?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="GET">
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['stack'], $_SESSION['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['stack'] = range(1, 10);                     // single point of adjustment as your project evolves/expands
    shuffle($_SESSION['stack']);                           // no subsequent rand() calls; shuffle once and only once
    $_SESSION['id'] = 0;                                   // init the current id
    $_SESSION['last_id'] = sizeof($_SESSION['stack']) - 1; // store the highest index
    echo "Ready to start this thing?";
    echo "<button>Let's Go!</button>";
} else {
    if (isset($_GET['back'])) {
        --$_SESSION['id'];                                 // decrement
    } elseif (isset($_GET['next'])) {
        ++$_SESSION['id'];                                 // increment
    }

    if ($_SESSION['id'] > $_SESSION['last_id']) {
        echo "<h1>Congratulations, you've finished.</h1>";
        session_destroy();                                     // just for my testing
        echo "<button>Play again?</button>";
    } else {
        echo "<div>DISPLAY sql{$_SESSION['stack'][$_SESSION['id']]}.php as page " . ($_SESSION['id'] + 1) . " of " . ($_SESSION['last_id'] + 1) ."</div>";
        //include("sql{$_SESSION['id']}.php");  // I recommend an absolute path to avoid monkeybusiness

        if ($_SESSION['id'] == 0) {
            echo "<button disabled>No Way</button>";
        } else {
            echo "<button name=\"back\">Back</button>";
        }
        if ($_SESSION['id'] == $_SESSION['last_id']) {
            echo "<button name=\"next\">Finish</button>";
        } else {
            echo "<button name=\"next\">Next</button>";
        }
    }
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Michael what is the status of this question?  It appears to be abandoned.